# Создание ZIP-архива программно

Tags: java, android, zip

Здравствуйте! Уже несколько дней мучаюсь с проблемой:
Мне нужно программно создать архив, и поместить в него файлы из массива.
Использовал cледующий код:

```
private static final int BUFFER = 80000;

public void zip(String[] _files, String zipFileName) {
    try {
        BufferedInputStream origin = null;
        FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(zipFileName);
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                dest));
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

        for (int i = 0; i < _files.length; i++) {
            Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]);
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]);
            origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
            out.putNextEntry(entry);
            int count;

            while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            origin.close();
        }

        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Вроде все идет хорошо, архив на месте, но:
Сам архив должен весить порядка 15 МБ, а весит всего 10,56 МБ, и архиватор говорит: "Архив поврежден". Возможно, конечно, вес сокращен из-за сжатия, но почему архиватор отказывается открывать его, и как убрать сжатие? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Можете подсказать, я так понимаю, что переменная private static final int BUFFER = 80000; нужна для того, чтоб указать какого размера файл будет создаваться?

Comment: Нет. Это размер именно буфера длячтения, смотрите как устроен bufferedinputstream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема у вас в том, что вы обрабатываете не все исключения и закрываете выходной поток не в секции finally, вот так примерно должен выглядеть рабочий код

```
private static final int BUFFER = 80000;

public void zip(String[] files, String zipFileName) {
    ZipOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName)));
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            processFile(out, data, files[i]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close(out);
    }
}

private void processFile(ZipOutputStream out, byte[] data, String file) {
    BufferedInputStream origin = null;
    try {
        origin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), BUFFER);
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
        out.putNextEntry(entry);
        int count;
        while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
            out.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close(origin);
    }
}

private void close(Closeable closeable){
    if (null != closeable){
        try {
            closeable.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А не подскажите, как сделать, чтобы код распозновал пути к папкам в массиве, и добавлял их в архив, пожалуйста? А то все файлы в архиве в одной директории. Знаю, что надо использовать isDirectory(), но как осуществить это, если пути в файлам хранятся в массиве?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740375/directories-in-a-zip-file-when-using-java-util-zip-zipoutputstream

Comment: Можете подсказать, я так понимаю, что переменная private static final int BUFFER = 80000; нужна для того, чтоб указать какого размера файл будет создаваться?